# Using jQuery AJAX to load PHP function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have been looking for a way to make my site a little sleeker, it's a casino with a few php games.

Each step you take in the game refreshes the page, one of my games is a slot game and on mobile you can't see the animation of the slot as it has run before you can scroll down and see it..

I would like to implement ajax to my site so rather than a page refresh the images change and that is it.

I have had a look at the jQuery AJAX API guide and I cant make heads or tails of it all I need to do is run a php function through ajax when a button is clicked

How hard is this to do?

I have this code which I've been told is on the right lines but how do I use it?

```
$.ajax({ url: '/lib/casinofile',
     data: {action: 'spin-wheel'},
     type: 'post',
     success: function(spinwheel) {
                  alert(spinwheel);

              }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi!! What returns in the console?

Comment: @Igor Martins In the slot game it returns 3 pictures, if you match 3 then you win a code prize the site is cdkey-hut.com/casino.php - I thought it might be easier to just link you than try to explain it

Answer (score 0):

well this code basically issue a POST request to /lib/casinofile, when the casinofile is returned by the server the success function is triggered...in this case it will create a popup in your browser with the response of the server(in this case it is spinwheel).

you could have done it in another way:
    $.post('/lib/casinofile/,{action:'spin-wheel'},function(data){
        alert(data);
    });

Comment: Ah okay, well I dont want a popup so I'll remove the alert. Does the name of the variable ($ajax(xx)) matter? And how do i link this to a form? the functions are triggered when a button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have the PHP script that you're sending the data to ("casinofile") to act on the data AJAX sends it and then return some instructions. For example, with the code above,  you might have in PHP:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'spin-wheel') {
    echo spinWheel();
}
```

This will return the result of spinWheel(), which might be, depending on what game we're taking about (I'm assuming roulette), 6B (6 black). The success function will load the resulting data `echo`ed by the PHP:

```
$.ajax({ url: '/lib/casinofile',
    data: {action: 'spin-wheel'},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result);

    }
});
```

Which will `alert()`,in this case, "B6."

Frankly, if possible, you may be better off re-writing the game in Javascript than trying to access your already-written PHP functions with AJAX. They should be easy enough to translate.

Comment: Sorry this is a bit of a noob question but in my form when I put an action it takes me to the page with the name of the action for example action='spin wheel' takes me to domain/spin%wheel is there a way I can do it with requests? $_REQUEST['submit']) == "Spin Wheel")

Comment: Also where would i put this code? On the actual page for the game I have a few if statements to check if the user has the funds to play and then it check to see if they have actually hit the button if $_REQUEST == xx and then it invokes a function called spinwheel would/could i put the ajax code in place of the function obviously closing the ?> first?

Answer (score 0):

To stop the page from refreshing, you're going to need to add

```
 return false;
```

in your script. Make sure it's at the end of the script, nothing afterwards will be executed.

That's just one step, you'll also need a separate .php file to execute your code.
And that's a whole different story.

This tutorial might get you going in the right direction: 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First at all, you couldn't load a function from your side server ( php script ) to you client side ( javascript ), however you could execute ( run ) a server side function and get your results on your client side. It is really simple, probably you have more than one function on that file, then we do at your java script

```
$.ajax({ 
     url: '/lib/casinofile.php',
     data: {
         action: 'spin-wheel'
     },
     type: 'post',
     success: function(spinwheelMessage) {
                  alert(spinwheelMessage);

              }
});
```

on your php file will be

```
<?php

function spinWheel () {
    /** something to do here **/
    return 'Hey, this is really simple';
}

if ($_POST['action'] == 'spin-wheel') {
    echo spinWheel ();
}
```

Don't forget to name your php file as php file, I mean *casinofile.php* instead just *casinofile*, mainly cause if your lib folder has not a restriction, it could be called and display your test as simple text